# Spring mvc -Properties file encoding

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a problem reading some character in a property file in Spring MVC.

I know properties file are encoded in ISO-8859-1 so I set my messageSource bean to set the default encode to UTF-8

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Before this modification, for example I saw the *à* character as *ï¿½*, after the *à* became *?*

I've also tried to use `ReloadedResourceBundleMessageSource` with no effect

How can I display just *à*?

Answer (score 0):

the javadoc states the following:

> Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be
>   written using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™
>   Language Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an
>   escape sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property
>   files to and from other character encodings.
>   Source [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

I been using that approach when I work with the ISO-8859-1 encoding (For example: `number=N\u00famero`) for a while but now I use the ReloadedResourceBundleMessageSource like you describe and it works flawlessly, as far I can know your properties file should be encoded using UTF-8 as well, you could try to encode your file using `native2ascii` like this example:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 file1.properties file2.properties
```